# Xray Overall Requirement Coverage Report

Tags: selenium-webdriver, cucumber, report, jira, jira-xray

I am trying to generate Overall Requirement Coverage Report using Xray plugin for Jira.

No matter what I do, it seems like it is not possible to separate Stories covered by Cucumber Test type issue and the ones covered by Manual Test issue.
[Generated report - Stories covered by Manual and Cucumber test types](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xxxG0.png)

On the issue screen within the Test Coverage section, it is possible to differentiate both types, but I could not manage to do it when generating coverage reports.[Test Coverage section](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5KlJ7.png)

Is there another way to generate a report, showing what is the Cucumber coverage of a project?

Answer (score 0):

Xray doesn't differentiate explictly if tests are running through automation or run manually.
Usually, Cucumber scenarios have test automation code associated with them... but not always. People can still execute those Cucumber scenarios manually.
For that and other reasons, you don't have an explicit way to make reports that show you the %tests automated or derivated reports.

Besides, coverage in Xray is not a percentage; it takes into account the results from all tests you performed, no matter how.

Going to your initial need, you could use the "scope" to accomplish it. You would do it as follows:

1. create a Test Plan with all the Cucumber tests and analyse the coverage based on that Test Plan. This implies that your Cucumber results would need to be associated with this Test Plan (you'll need to use the multipart specific Cucumber endpoint for that)
2. create another Test Plan for manual testing efforts.. and analyze coverage based on that

More on analysis by Test Plan [here](https://docs.getxray.app/display/XRAY/Coverage+Analysis#CoverageAnalysis-TestPlan) and [here](https://docs.getxray.app/display/XRAY/Test+Coverage#TestCoverage-TestPlan).